# Database alters and Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to run alters on the embedded derby database after a desktop application has been updated. To do this I attempted to create a JPS repository with my alter queries similar to this:

```
@Repository
public interface DatabaseUpdates {
    @Modifying
    @Query("alter table my_table add column my_column clob", nativeQuery = true)
    void alterMyTableAddMyColumn();
}
```

And use it in the updater class like this

```
@Component
public class DatabaseUpdater {
    @Autowired
    private DatabaseUpdates databaseUpdates;

    private void alterMyTable() {
        // some logic that checks it the update needs to happen is here
        databaseUpdates.alterMyTableAddMyColumn();
    }
}
```

This throws `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type DatabaseUpdates` exceptions.

I also tried having `DatabaseUpdates` extend `org.springframework.data.repository.Repository` but then had problems with what to use as the domain type.

I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` 1.2.3.RELEASE.

**Edit:** This is to support a legacy app and I am looking for straight forward ways to support database updates. Database migrations tools are great but not in scope for this fix. I've been wishing this project had been using one for more than a month now and will be integrating one into the next version soon.

Comment: So you think this "alter table my_table add column my_column clob" is JPQL? Well it's not. It's SQL.

Comment: @NeilStockton I forgot the `nativeQuery = true` flag sorry. I'm attempting to solve some issues with a legacy codebase and am not familiar with JPA or Spring.

Comment: @nash do the alters really need to happen at runtime? you can't simply make them to to the database directly? If so, could you get away with creating a simple Key/Value table that allows you to various data elements and associate them back to a record? e.g. instead of adding column X with value Y to table Q you could create a table with an FK to the Q record, and a Key and value column. Thus you could be completely extensible (though you lose type safety, but if you're using clobs you lose that anyway)

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like an awful idea. There are frameworks, which were specifically developed for your usecase and are supported by Spring Boot, like [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) and [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/). You are then able to specify your changes either in SQL or Java code (for Flyway) or in an XML, SQL, YAML or JSON file (for Liquibase). Those frameworks will check which migrations are necessary and they also keep track when a migration was executed.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. The application is effectively legacy at this point and I am looking for straight forward solutions to upgrading the database. I already have plans for integrating a database migration tool in the next version.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't put this in Spring JPA. If you mention it is temporary, maybe try some JDBC directly and run the queries on the database. Try to log the changes you make in a table (something similar to what liquibase is doing), so you don't run the queries multiple times.
Maybe try to run this before Spring builds your `DataSource` in your `DatabaseConfiguration` class.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaRepositories("")
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public class DatabaseConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {

            @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
            public DataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties, ApplicationProperties applicationProperties)
                    throws SQLException {
                LOG.debug("Configuring Datasource");
                //some code
                alterSchema();
                return new HikariDataSource(config);
            }

            private void alterSchema() {
              // JDBC connection and queries to alter the schema
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your repository can execute a `transaction` and build a `native query` with an `EntityManager` like the following code

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Repository
public class DatabaseUpdates{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    //ALTER TABLE `my_table` ADD COLUMN `my_column` VARCHAR(100) AFTER `after_column`;
    @Transactional
    public void alterMyTableAddMyColumn(String tableName, String columnName, 
        String columnType, String afterColumnName) {

        String query = "ALTER TABLE `" + tableName + "` ADD COLUMN `" + columnName + "` " +
            columnType + " AFTER `" + afterColumnName + "`";

        entityManager.createNativeQuery(query).executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Your updater class calls your repository like this

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Component
public class DatabaseUpdater {
    @Autowired
    private DatabaseUpdates databaseUpdates;

    private void alterMyTable() {
        // some logic that checks it the update needs to happen is here
        String tableName = "my_table";
        String columnName = "my_column";
        String columnType = "VARCHAR(100)";
        String afterColumnName = "after_column";

        databaseUpdates.alterMyTableAddMyColumn(tableName, columnName, 
            columnType, afterColumnName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While not a best practice, you can temporarily use native JDBC, acquire connection from your existing DataSource. If you are only adding a column, make sure to check if the object(column) already exist.